# How do I send email on swift?

Tags: ios, swift, email, development-environment

I have followed peoples code on sending an email on swift and the problem is on my phone, the send button is greyed out. What do I do? Here is my code and a picture of the problem on my phone.

[The Problem On My Phone, The Send Button Is Greyed Out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUh1Z.png)

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class SendEmailViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    @IBAction func sendEmail(_ sender: Any)
    {
        let mailComposeViewController = configureMailController()
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            self.present(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            showMailError()
        }
    } 

    func configureMailController() -> MFMailComposeViewController
    {
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["abc@gmail.com"])
        mailComposerVC.setSubject("Gamifiction")
        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Hey, Check Out My Game", isHTML: false)

        return mailComposerVC    }

    func showMailError()
    {
        let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Could not send email", message: "Your device could not send email", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
        sendMailErrorAlert.addAction(dismiss)
        self.present(sendMailErrorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `configureMailController` before you call `canSendMail`?

Comment: Hey its greyed out becasue its my personal info thats there already behind it

Comment: My email is there its just behind the grey box that i put because i did not want people seeing my email

Comment: And would it matter if i call it beofre canSendMail

Comment: But you put your email in the code you posted.

Comment: It won't solve this issue (maybe) but it's pointless to call `configureMailController` is the device can't even send email.

Comment: hahahahahahahahahahaahahahah crap im dumb

Comment: Well I wasnt sure but I literally followed someone else code and it works fine for them in the video but for me the send is greyed out

Comment: my canSendMail is before my configureMailController but it still does not work